# WUSA standalone install

Tags: powershell

When I try and install my patches with power-shell script I get a wusa error message from the windows standalone installer. after I click ok from the popup the script appears to be installing the patch, however when I view the windows update history, my updates are not reflected. I'm not sure where I'm encountering the error but I know it's not due to power-shell syntax.

```
{
    Try 
        {
        Write-Host ("`n Preparing to install: " + $Patch) -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host ("`n Installing...") -ForegroundColor Magenta
        $SB = {
            $arglist = "$Patch", "/quiet", "/norestart"
            Start-Process -FilePath "C:\windows\system32\wusa.exe" -ArgumentList $arglist -Wait}
        Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock $SB
        Write-Host "`n Installation complete`n" -ForegroundColor Green
        }
    Catch 
        {
        [System.Exception]
        Write-Host "Installation failed with Error -- $Error()" -ForegroundColor Red
        $Error.Clear()
        }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You can't use WUSA remotely.

Comment: im getting the wusa help menu so it must be from the switches... and my question is why am i getting this error if my shell syntax is valid.

Comment: im rdp'ed into the remote box and im trying to run it locally on that box

Comment: Why the script? Why not just type the command to run and press `Enter`?

Comment: this is the command im running: wusa ie11-windows6.1-kb4103768-x64_6fdefd19b436dc21dc2fee3264d80fb078ea9f17 (1).msu /quiet /noRestart

Comment: That will throw an error because the filename argument to `wusa` contains whitespace. Quote it; e.g.: `wusa "ie11-windows6.1-kb4103768-x64_6fdefd19b436dc21dc2fee3264d80fb078ea9f17 (1).msu" /quiet /norestart`.

Comment: Thank you, I had a duplicate that added the (1) which gave whitespace!! thank you